# ProgrammingError: column ... must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: django, postgresql

Django's documentation mentions [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```py
q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'))
```

My code is full of similar constructs (adding a count of something to a queryset, using `annotate`), and this always worked well. Now suddenly, for reasons unknown, I'm getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError: column ... must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

In fact, I have the same version of Django on my `dev` and `prod`, and everything works on `dev`, but fails on `prod` (typical). Spontaneously. For no apparent reason.

And I cannot add the named column to the GROUP BY clause, because then it wants me to add the next column, and the next, and the next, etc. I can also not add some random aggregate function. In short: the solutions that the error mentions make no sense!

There are many more questions with this same error, many unanswered. I have no solution, but it seems this error started appearing lately, in Django versions 4+, at least for me.

I've tried the failing SQL query directly within Postgres and it fails there as well, of course, with exactly the same error. The fault is not with Django.

The only way to make this `annotate` query work, is when selecting distinct fields, like for example:

```py
q = Book.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('authors'))
```

But unfortunately that makes no sense in many cases within my project: I do need the whole object, not a single field.

It's seems logical to say that the version of Postgres changed on the server, but that isn't the case. Things broke after a failed deploy that I had to roll back. The database got corrupted in the process (there were actually double ID's in some tables). Afterwards this ProgrammingError appeared and some page requests fail with a 500 error.

Any clues to a solution?

UPDATE 1: It seems that there actually are queries, just like the one at the top of this post, that work well. At the same time there are others, that looks exactly the same, that don't work. I'm trying to pinpoint the difference. To be continued...

UPDATE 2: I can't really find a difference. I've updated this question to point at a more exact case. In my project it's, say, a `Product` model that has a `tags` property, which is a ManyToMany relation to a `Tag` model - exactly like the relation in the documentation of Django (Book model with a m2m property 'authors'). But it fails...

UPDATE 3: Additionally to the aforementioned case there's also this one:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    b = models.IntegerField()

class ModelC(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='cs')
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, related_name='cs')

ModelA.objects.annotate(c=Count('cs'))  # fails
ModelB.objects.annotate(c=Count('cs'))  # works!
```

Someone has an explanation for this one? (Of course ModelA and ModelB have more fields, does that matter?)

UPDATE 4: As I said, this problem only occured on `prod`, not on `dev`. So I was curious and copied the `prod` database to `dev`, and now this same problem appears on `dev` as well! Conclusion: this error appears because of the data in the database! Not the structure, not the version. As mentioned, this problems started occurring after a database corruption, so that's the key. How could I solve this? How to repair the DB corruption? Note: I've already repaired (as in: removed) all duplicate key and unique field issues, etc. Not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: You didn't share the query with the error?

Comment: I did, it's the one from Django's documentation: `Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))`

Comment: but there is no group by here at all? That one is failing?

Comment: You say your code is full of similar constructs, but likely there is a "technical detail" that raises the error. Therefore it might be better to share an actually query that fails.

Comment: The `annotate` with the `Count` performs a `GROUP BY` behind the screens (it joins the book table and then performs a group by on publisher.id).

Comment: yes, it performs a group by, but if you somehow tweak the query, it can result in constructing an invalid query (unfortunately Django's ORM is expressive, but not really guaranteed to make valid queries). Therefore it is important to share how you construct a specific problematic query.

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact case, which is the same as in Django's documentation. Possibly the error is caused by corrupt data in the tables? I'm still clueless...

Comment: If you have direct access to the databases, you could diff the DDL's between prod and test, compare the definitions of tables that store a problematic model. The failed deploy part sounds like an interrupted migration could've left some additional columns behind. Since it's the db that's throwing the error, it should be easier to trace this by looking at the actual, raw queries that reach the db and the objects they find there.

Comment: I have 2 dumps (of prod and dev), made with pg_dump -Fc option. How would I go about and compare table definitions?

Comment: [`pg_restore --schema-only --file=dev_schema.sql the_dump_file_name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html#APP-PGRESTORE-OPTIONS), same for prod. Then you can just read or `diff` these files, or just the part concerning the table holding one of the models that triggered the error.
About "UPDATE 4": The error you're getting results from structure, [it could even be empty](https://dbfiddle.uk/vzmnk7NA). How specifically did you "copy prod to dev"? What exactly do you mean by database corruption, what tells you that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summing up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731935/5298879):

1. `column ... must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` indicates mishandled [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html), or the structure you're dealing with is not what you expected it to be. The latter turned out to be the case here, due to uncontrolled structure change, failed deploy.
2. It's useful to inspect and compare the target structures, especially if you faced difficulties altering them without a clean restore from a reliable backup - in this case it's prod/dev, but you can also check before/after against a backup, for forensics/post-mortem. On most platforms, you can do so with [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [`diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) (or similarly [any alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/diffutils/)):

   ```bash
   diff --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side <( \
   pg_dump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username='your_user' --no-password \
           --format=plain --schema-only \
           --schema='the_problem_table_schema' \
           --table='the_problem_table_schema.the_problem_table' \
           dev_database ) <( \
   pg_dump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username='your_user' --no-password \
           --format=plain  --schema-only \
           --schema='the_problem_table_schema' \
           --table='the_problem_table_schema.the_problem_table' \
           prod_database )
   ```

   (substitute you connection parameters and object names)

Answer (score 1):

The comments of @Zegarek pointed me in the right direction. Gathering schema information about both databases (prod and dev) showed that important constraints were missing on the prod database, namely: `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints, exactly on those tables that were causing the `column ... must appear in the GROUP BY` error. I'm not sure how it is they're missing (as the dev database is simply the prod db of a month ago), but adding the constraints on-the-fly solved the problem - no more ProgrammingError!

When the prod db got corrupted there were duplicates exactly on those fields where the constraint was missing. That should have been a little hint.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an aggregation on fieldname you have excluded in the queryset. In you case, you have query only `name` by calling `values`. Are you sure it is necessary to use values function ? In most cases, You do not need to retrieve dictionnary of values.

Django explains usage of `values` function here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values

```py
pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
pubs = Publisher.objects.values('book').annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

Comment: You *can* make an aggregation on a fieldname that is not in a `values()`. In fact, it's the only way to make the error disappear, as I mention in the question. So this works perfectly well: `pubs = Publisher.objects.values('name').annotate(num_books=Count('book'))`. Problem: it returns a list of dicts with `name` and `num_books`, instead of `Publisher` objects, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Yes you have to remove values() in you query if you do not want to retrieve dictionnary. It is what i told you in my post and what the documentation explains. So i do not understand what is the problem ? If you want to retrieve only `book` and `num_books`, you can use `only` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)
I did not see your last edit. ok so you can use `only`